# Simply use my own custom javascript in an erb file in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have been Googling and beating my head up against a wall for 2 days and now I finally just need to ask you guys.

I want to simply create a Javascript file in Rails 6 and then call the function on a button in an erb file.

THAT'S IT.

Why is this not the simplest thing in the world?

After realizing that I was getting 2 different sets of instructions from the internet, one for rails 5 and previous and the other for rails 6, I tried looking for specifically Rails 6 answers. They were still much too complicated for such a simple problem and often were about bringing in external libraries. I don't want external libraries. I want my own javascript. And I want to call it in my erb files.

I appreciate anyone helping me out on this.

Comment: If you want a specific example. Literally a function called test() in a test.js file  that alerts "hello world". From my javascript file to my erb file button.

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: Assume that i've just created a rails new. I have my file structure, i have webpack and yarn. Maybe I've created a route, controller, model, and view. and I have an index page and I just want one button that when I click on it the alert from my javascript file test.js is working. Where am I putting the file test.js and how is my index file going to know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `application.js` already in `packs` directory, create a new file `custom.js` in the same directory, since you want this to be accessible everywhere, you need to put it in `window` scope, add this in the file

```
window.testFun = function(){
  alert('Hello World!');
}
```

Then `require` the file in `application.js`

```
require("custom")
```

Now you can call this `onclick` in erb file in application.

```
<%= link_to 'Test', '#', onclick: "testFun()" %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to 'Test', "javascript:testFun()" %>
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's literally all I needed. You are the best!

Comment: @AndrewRichards Happy to help!